# How do you allow sequence outputs in recurrent layers?

Tags: neural-networks

I'd like to train this reverse-uppercase sample data:

```
train = Table[With[{h = StringJoin@RandomSample[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 4]}, 
              h -> ToUpperCase@StringReverse@h], 10]
```

which looks like this:

`{"lqsz" -> "ZSQL", "vozt" -> "TZOV", "adgk" -> "KGDA", ...}`

But I'm confused as to how to specify that the output of the RNN should be a sequence. The examples in the docs such as learning addition have single integer outputs, so they use `SequenceLastLayer[]`, for example.

When I try something like this:

```
net = NetChain[{UnitVectorLayer[], GatedRecurrentLayer[40], 
      GatedRecurrentLayer[30]}, "Input" -> "Characters", 
      "Output" -> "Characters"]
```

I get this error:

```
NetChain::invspdec: NetDecoder of type Characters, which expects either a     
length-97 vector or a n*97 matrix, cannot be attached to port Output, which 
produces a n*30 matrix.
```

If I try to replace the `30` with `97` in the code above, then there is no error here, but when I try to actually train it with:

```
model = NetTrain[net, train]
```

then I get this error:

```
NetTrain::invindim: Data provided to port "Output" should be a list of n*97 matrices.
```

What's the right way to specify sequences as outputs? And more generally, not just characters, but what if it is a sequence of vector inputs mapping to a sequence of vector outputs.

Comment: To allow output sequence of varying length, you have to encode the start and stop tokens. Take a look at the "integer addition" example in the documentation in `NetTrain`, the last approach in that example should work for your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I saw the integer addition examples in GRU, LSTM, etc., and those were much shorter. The one you suggest is so much more thorough. Thank you very much for the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
net = NetGraph[
  <|
   "enc" -> {UnitVectorLayer[], GatedRecurrentLayer[40]},
   "att" -> SequenceAttentionLayer[],
   "dec" -> GatedRecurrentLayer[40],
   "cat" -> CatenateLayer[2],
   "classify" -> NetMapOperator[NetChain[{LinearLayer[26], SoftmaxLayer[]}]]
   |>,
  {
   "enc" -> NetPort["att", "Input"],
   "enc" -> "dec" -> NetPort["att", "Query"],
   {"dec", "att"} -> "cat" -> "classify"
   },
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Characters", StringJoin@CharacterRange["a", "z"]}],
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Characters", StringJoin@CharacterRange["A", "Z"]}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1234];
X = StringJoin /@ RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], {100000, 4}];
Y = UnitVectorLayer[26]@NetEncoder[{"Characters", StringJoin@CharacterRange["A", "Z"]}]@
    ToUpperCase@StringReverse@X;

netT = NetTrain[net, X -> Y, MaxTrainingRounds -> 1]

Thread[X[[;; 10]] -> netT@X[[;; 10]]]
```

> {"buwu" -> "UWUB", "byaq" -> "QAYB", "reft" -> "TFER", 
>    "zpqt" -> "TQPZ", "cymf" -> "FMYC", "qsxu" -> "UXSQ", 
>    "hovq" -> "QVOH", "gbpx" -> "XPBG", "hinw" -> "WNIH", 
>    "nbpw" -> "WPBN"}

Comment: This is simply gorgeous.

Comment: @PhilipMaymin I was glad to help you.